# Unable to replace '-' with underscore using my approach in javascript

Tags: javascript

Good evening Friends!
When I try to run the below mentioned function in chrome console, output comes out but minus sign is unreplaced.

```js
function kebabToSnake(kebab){
  var i=0;
  for(i=0;i<kebab.length;i++){
  if(kebab[i]=='-'){
    kebab[i]='_';
  }
  }
  var newStr=kebab;
  return newStr;
}
console.log(kebabToSnake("a-b-c-d"));
```

Even if i try to return kebab without creating newStr , still does not work . I already know the replace method in javascript . Just want to know why this method does not work out !

Comment: Strings are immutable in JavaScript. Reassigning an index in them doesn't change the string.

Comment: Tip: add `"use strict";` on top of your code and you'll get a meaningful error message in the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `kebab.replace(/-/g, '_')` but assume that's not an option for you, so you actually want to iterate over the characters and replace them one by one.

[Strings in JavaScript are immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable), so `kebab[i] = '_'` won't work.

You need to split the string in an array of characters using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and iterate over them while doing the replacements you need, either by replacing the elements (characters) in the array or creating a new one, like in the example below, using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Then, you join the characters again using [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
function kebabToSnake(str) {
  return str.split('').map((char) => {
    return char === '-' ? '_' : char;
  }).join('');
}

console.log(kebabToSnake('foo-bar-baz'))
```

Comment: thank you very much